# Ruby: get sum of nested hash value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i have hash departments

```
{"Mechnical" => {"boys" => "25", "girls"=>"5"}, "Civil"=> {"boys"=>"18", "girls"=>"12"}}
```

i want output like this,

```
{"Mechanical" => "30", "Civil => "30"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below

```
# If you are in Ruby 2.1 or greater
your_hash.map { |k,v| [k, v.reduce(0) { |sum, (_, v)| sum + v.to_i }] }.to_h
# => {"Mechnical"=>30, "Civil"=>30} 

# below Ruby 2.1
Hash[your_hash.map { |k,v| [k, v.reduce(0) { |sum, (_, v)| sum + v.to_i }] }]
# => {"Mechnical"=>30, "Civil"=>30}

# for all versions
your_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), h| 
  h[k] = v.reduce(0) { |sum, (_, v)| sum + v.to_i }
end
# => {"Mechnical"=>30, "Civil"=>30}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hsh = { "Mechnical" => {"boys" => "25", "girls"=>"5"}, "Civil"=> {"boys"=>"18", "girls"=>"12"} } 

hsh.map { |d, s| [d, s.sum {|_, c| c.to_i} ] }.to_h
# => {"Mechnical"=>30, "Civil"=>30}
```

If count is a number rather than a String, you can do

```
hsh.map { |d, s| [d, s.sum(&:last) ] }.to_h
# => {"Mechnical"=>30, "Civil"=>30}
```

Since you are using Rails, `sum` will work, other wise use `inject(:+)`

Thanks Arup for pointing out the redundancy of 2 intermediate arrays.

**EDIT**

Ruby has  [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) since 2.4.0

Comment: Why did you _suggest_ 2 extra intermediate arrays ? (`v.values.map(&:to_i)`)